# match csv data with RegExp, Python

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have a csv file which contains lines like:

```
{"Books \u3009 Arts & Photography \u3009 Sculpture \u3009  Appreciation": 342444, "Books": 4244234234875}
{"Books \u3009 Science": 342864, "Books": 44242875}
{"Books \u3009 Politics": 342444, "Books": 4135875}
```

I need to read csv file and match `"Books": \d+`, I need only that number, and put it in a new csv file

```
import csv
import json
import re
with open('input.csv', 'rb') as infile:
    with open('output.csv', 'wb',) as outfile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        for line_num, line in enumerate(reader):
            result = re.match(r'^"Books":(\d+)$', line[0])
            writer.writerow([result])
```

But the code doesn't work properly, basically I receive blank cells, which means I cannot match required data. If I match `.*`, I receive '<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x028B2800>'.
Tried different approaches, please, push me in right direction. Thanks

Comment: *Is* that a CSV file? With the `{}`s it looks more like broken JSON, or someone has just dumped dictionary literals into a file. Note that the beginning of a string in your case is `{` not `"Books` - what happens if you `print(line[0])`? And why did getting a `SRE_Match` object surprise you, that's what's supposed to happen!

Comment: `result.group(1)` and perhaps `re.search`  is more appropriate.

Comment: Probably the reason it's not working is that there's a space between the `:` and the number that you're not accounting for in the pattern. But I agree with jonrsharpe... that doesn't look like a good candidate for interpreting as a CSV.

Comment: Also, shouldn't `line[0]` be `line[1]`? It looks like you intended to use `json`, and a cursory glance indicates that you can probably do away with both `csv` and `re` if you do so.

Comment: Yes, you're right, someone put such JSONs in csv, but as they are broken, I couldn't parse it with json.loads(), and decided to match it with RegExp. Ok, thanks, will try with re.search

Comment: Each of the given lines interprets just fine with `json.loads` for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a CSV file but a bunch of JSON objects put together. They all appear valid, so you can just parse them and extract the data that way:

```
import csv
import json

with open('input.csv', 'r') as infile, open('output.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for line in infile:
        num_books = json.loads(line.strip())['Books']
        writer.writerow([num_books])
```

Tested in python 3.4.

Comment: Thanks, your code pushed me to some thought and I realised, that the first row in the file was just a string (name of a column), and the starting from the second row - JSON objects begin, that's why I couldn't parse the JSON, as I need to miss the first row and Parse from the second. Now code works